# Wordpress .Htaccess Usage In Subfolder Site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Could someone help me; where am i doing wrong?

My wordpress site is not in root; i installed it in a directory(newsite/) I mean; there are 2 sites.

My root site(example.com) has default htaccess file.

And this is my sub wordpress site's(example.com/newsite/) .htacces source:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /newsite/
RewriteRule ^newsite/news/hello-world /newsite/news/?title=hello-world [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /newsite/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I just want:

**www.example.com/newsite/news/hello-world**

(above url should open the url at below; without url change at address bar)

**www.example.com/newsite/news/?title=hello-world**

Answer (score 0):

Check with different permalink options.
Note : .htaccess file should be writable or paste the suggested code in .htaccess after permalink saved.